# Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed when retrying http connection - ESP32

Tags: firebase, https, arduino, ssl-certificate, arduino-c++

I have problem with configuring SSL layer with http client - I am posting data to the Firebase server in a loop, with connectionKeepAlive, when i want to close the connection with http.stop, and then run http.connect(SERVER, SSL_PORT) again - in next iteration,
I get an exception: Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed

Code based: https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/T-A7608X/blob/main/examples/Arduino/GPS_NMEA_Parse/GPS_NMEA_Parse.ino

Modifications:

```
const char root_ca[] PROGMEM = <Firebase cert>
SSLClient secure_layer(&client);
HttpClient http = HttpClient(secure_layer, FIREBASE_HOST, SSL_PORT);
```

```
void setup() {

secure_layer.setCACert(root_ca);
}
```

```
void loop()
{
    Serial.print(F("Connecting to network"));
    if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
        Serial.println(" fail");
        delay(1000);
        return;
    }
    
    Serial.println(" OK");

    http.connect(FIREBASE_HOST, SSL_PORT);
    
    while (true) {
        if (!http.connected()) {
            Serial.println();
            http.stop();// Shutdown
            Serial.println("HTTP  not connect");
            break;
        }
        else {
            gps_loop();
        }
    }
}
```

```
gps_loop(){
...
String gpsData = "{";
    gpsData += "\"latitude\":" + latitude + ",";
    gpsData += "\"longitude\":" + longitude + ",";
    gpsData += "\"date\":" + datetime + "";
    gpsData += "}";

    PostToFirebase("PATCH", FIREBASE_PATH, gpsData, &http);
    }
```

And the problematic one:

```
void PostToFirebase(const char* method, const String & path , const String & data, HttpClient* http) {
  String response;
  int statusCode = 0;
  http->connectionKeepAlive(); // Currently, this is needed for HTTPS
  
  //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
  String url;
  if (path[0] != '/') {
    url = "/";
  }
  url += path + ".json";
  url += "?auth=" + FIREBASE_AUTH;
  Serial.print("POST:");
  Serial.println(url);
  Serial.print("Data:");
  Serial.println(data);
  //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
  
  String contentType = "application/json";
  http->put(url, contentType, data);
  
  //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
  // read the status code and body of the response
  //statusCode-200 (OK) | statusCode -3 (TimeOut)
  statusCode = http->responseStatusCode();
  Serial.print("Status code: ");
  Serial.println(statusCode);
  response = http->responseBody();
  Serial.print("Response: ");
  Serial.println(response);
  //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN

  //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
  if (!http->connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    http->stop();// Shutdown
    Serial.println("HTTP POST disconnected");
  }
  //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
}
```

Output:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core 1 register dump:
PC : 0x400d5659 PS : 0x00060e30 A0 : 0x800d525e A1 : 0x3ffb20e0
A2 : 0x3ffb9d0c A3 : 0x3f4007e5 A4 : 0x00000000 A5 : 0x00000000
A6 : 0x00ff0000 A7 : 0xff000000 A8 : 0x800d5cd4 A9 : 0x3ffb20c0
A10 : 0x00000000 A11 : 0x3f40340d A12 : 0x00000002 A13 : 0xffffffff
A14 : 0x00ff0000 A15 : 0xff000000 SAR : 0x0000000a EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000 LBEG : 0x400864c1 LEND : 0x400864d1 LCOUNT : 0xfffffffd

Backtrace: 0x400d5656:0x3ffb20e0 0x400d525b:0x3ffb2100 0x400d4cd4:0x3ffb2120 0x400d27f6:0x3ffb2140 0x400d40a9:0x3ffb21b0 0x400d41d0:0x3ffb2270 0x400d6df9:0x3ffb2290
```

Decoded:

```
PC: 0x400d5651: stop_ssl_socket(sslclient_context*, char const*, char const*, char const*) at C:\XXX\Arduino\libraries\SSLClient\src\ssl_client.cpp line 339
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000

Decoding stack results
0x400d564e: stop_ssl_socket(sslclient_context*, char const*, char const*, char const*) at C:\XXX\Arduino\libraries\SSLClient\src\ssl_client.cpp line 336
0x400d5253: SSLClient::stop() at C:\XXX\Arduino\libraries\SSLClient\src\SSLClient.cpp line 69
0x400d4ccc: HttpClient::stop() at C:\XXX\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoHttpClient\src\HttpClient.cpp line 47
0x400d27f6: PostToFirebase(char const*, String const&, String const&, HttpClient*) at D:\XXX\sketch_jun14a/sketch_jun14a.ino line 387
0x400d40a9: gps_loop() at D:\XXX\sketch_jun14a/sketch_jun14a.ino line 307
0x400d41c8: loop() at D:\XXX\sketch_jun14a/sketch_jun14a.ino line 232
0x400d6df1: loopTask(void*) at C:\XXXi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.9\cores\esp32\main.cpp line 50
```

What is a proper way to close the https connection with SSL and connectionKeepAlive defined before? What is exactly happening here?